# Kivy checkboxes don't work in ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I can't figure out why checkboxes don't work in a `ScrollView`. The following code and .kv file do not allow checkboxes to be clicked unless I remove the `ScrollView`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen)
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


class MainManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Scrolling(ScrollView):
    pass

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class QuestionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        AppSM = MainManager()
        AppSM.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
        return AppSM

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QuestionApp().run()
```

and .kv file

```
<LoginScreen>:
    Scrolling:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: 15
            spacing: 50
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            Button:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '200sp'
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                CheckBox:
                    active: False
                CheckBox:
                    active: True
<Scrolling>:
    do_scroll_x: False
    bar_margin: 0
    bar_width: 15
    bar_color: [.7,.7,.7,.9]
    bar_inactive_color: [.7,.7,.7,.9]
    scroll_type: ['bars','content']
```

If I change `<LoginScreen>:` to the following, removing the scrolling, the checkboxes work just fine:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        padding: 15
        spacing: 50
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '200sp'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            CheckBox:
                active: False
            CheckBox:
                active: True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `kv` file to this:

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 200
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    CheckBox:
        active: False
    CheckBox:
        active: True
```

then the `CheckBox`es work (at least for me). The reason why is most likely because of the explicitly stated height, which I think the `GridLayout` expects when you set `height: self.minimum_height`.

Comment: This worked.  A bit confusing as I assumed the self.minimum_height of GridLayout was for the total size of the Layout itself, needed to contain each element and that each element would take up at a minimum its default size - but looking through the docs it seems checkboxes don't have a default size, whereas other widgets do - hence why the buttons worked.

Comment: @Daniel they do actually have a default size, as any other widget that inherits from `Widget` class -> `[100, 100]`, the problem is that `size_hint` has higher priority. Even `size_hint_y: None` does the thing.